# Function execution uses old prop values instead of new prop values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React functional components and here are my codes:

Parent component function:

```
const calculateAPR = async (val) => {
        setIsAprLoading(true);
        try {
            if (val.addr !== "" && val.date !== null) {
                const totalStaking = await someEP.getSomeData(val.addr);
                val.staked = totalStaking;
                setResData((prevState) => {
                    return ({
                        ...prevState,
                        aprRes: val
                    })
                })
                setRenderApr(true);
                setIsAprLoading(false);
            }
            else {
                setRenderApr(false);
                alert(Constants.ADDR_N_DATE_ERR);
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            setRenderApr(false);
            console.log(err);
            alert(Constants.ADDR_NO_DATA);
        }
        finally {
            setIsAprLoading(false);
        }  
    }
...
return (
...
    <QueryAprField text={Constants.CALC_APR_HEADER} onFunction={calculateAPR} isLoading={isAprLoading} />
    <CalculateAprField resData={resData.aprRes} onRender={renderApr} />
...
)
```

Child component 1:

```
function QueryAprField(props) {
...
    const handleQuery = () => {
        const verify = verifyDelegatorAddress();
        if (verify) {
            props.onFunction(queryValue);
        }
        else {
            alert(Constants.ENTER_VALID_DEL_ADDR);
        }
    }
...handles taking in user inputs and passing it to parent component...
}
```

Child component 2:

```
function CalculateAprField(props) {

    const aprRes = props.resData;
    ...

        const renderCard = () => {
        if (renderData == true) {
            const aprInput = setAprInputs(aprRes);
            const { staked } = extractAprInput(aprInput);
            const apr = parseFloat(calculateAPR(staked, accrued, withdrawn, numOfDays).toFixed(5));
            if (isNaN(apr)) {

                //How to reset aprRes and ensure that its not using old values

                return alert(Constants.APR_AUTO_ERR)
            }
            return (
                <Paper elevation={4}>
                    ...some html and css...
                </Paper>
            )
        }
    }

    return (
        <Box>
            {renderCard()}
        </Box>
    )
```

I'm trying to enable a situation where, after `calculateAPR` in the parent component is executed, some data will be passed to child component 2; and in child component 2 in the `renderCard` function, if the variable `apr` in child component 2 is `NaN` then an alert will be triggered. However, the problem I'm facing now is that after the alert is triggered, and when I put in new values and execute `calculateAPR` again, child component 2 seems to use the old values first before using the new values that are passed down from the parent component. So in other words, I get the alert first and then it uses the new values that are being passed down.

How can I enable the `aprRes` variable in child component 2, to reset its value after the alert is thrown? So that the alert is not thrown twice?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to reset the value. component rerenders only on props change.
I see the problem could be with this line. const aprInput = setAprInputs(aprRes); React setState doesn't return anything. Please change it to below and try once.

setAprInputs(aprRes);

(or)

if aprInput is not used anywhere else better extract from aprRes only.

```
const { staked } = extractAprInput(aprRes);
```

Incase if setAprInputs is not a setState rather a user-defined function, ensure it is a synchronous function and console.log after the call.

hope this gives you some insight to debug.